# How does the updateAction modify stock in the Cart Controller

Tags: php, magento, cart

i've modified the cart in the magento installation i'm working on so that when you want to change the size of a price of clothing (from say Small to Large) you can do it by using a drop down box rather than having to remove the item and re add it with the new size, how i do this is that i remove the old size from the cart and add the new size (in a sense, how one would do it if the functionality wasn't there)

i have also edited the cart so that if you was to change the size of a product from say Small to Large and you already have a product with the size of Large it will merge the 2's quantity if there is enough in stock (so if you want to change 5 Small into 5 Large and you already have 3 large, the cart will have after the update 8 large), how i do this is by checking if the size your changing to already is in the cart, if so, check to see if there is enough stock, if so then remove the item your changing the size of and edited the `$cartData` variable which handles qty changes for existing items so it alters the quantity, both of these work

the problem i have found out however is that if you was to have a cart like this

```
product   | size   | qty
---------------------------------------
product 1 | Large  | 1
product 1 | Medium | 1
product 1 | Small  | 1
```

and you was to change the large to a small and the small to a large, you'll get an error if you don't have enough stock even though your not increasing it

i've worked out that it's because of my method of changing sizes when the size doesn't exists in the cart, even though i remove the item from the cart the qty is still gone from the stock, in other words, if you had an item with only 1 in stock and you removed it and added the same item in again with a qty of 1, magento would think that your trying to have an item with a qty of 2.

now obviously, the solution to my problem with swapping product sizes is to force magento to update the stock every i remove an item from the cart in updateAction, however even looking at the original updateAction in the CartController.php file i can't seem to find the function where magento updates the stock levels it's using when items are in the cart however i know it must update some temp stock levels as i've notice that even if you have have say 5 of an item, 5 isn't missing from the stock in the database

my question is that how does the updateAction modify stock in the Cart Controller, once i find out how it does i can go about forcing it to work in the middle of my updateAction rather than the end

NOTE: i know it seems stupid to just swap 2 sizes of the same product (effectively swapping their positions in the cart) however i have to assume that users are idiots and they'll do something stupid like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`updateAction` does not modify product stock. Product stock is decreased by `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer::subtractQuoteInventory` method which is triggered on `sales_model_service_quote_submit_before` event (see `app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/etc/config.xml` file)